# Axis2 & Java_Home Error?

Tags: apache2, java

You'll have to forgive me as I'm still learning the in's and out's of Ubuntu. I have come across an error that I cannot seem to find anywhere else but know that it has something to do with my JAVA_HOME setup.

I am generating the code via Axis2 in SOAPUI and get the following log back:

```
Running Axis2 wsdl2java for [TrackingSoap]
directory: /home/mprythero/axis2-1.7.4/bin
command: [sh, -c, ./wsdl2java.sh -uri /tmp/tempdir4960219680155655293.tmp/tracking_1.wsdl -o /var/www/html/rrts -d adb -s -g -u -sn Tracking -pn TrackingSoap -Ew false -ns2p ]
You must set the JAVA_HOME variable before running Axis2 Script.
export DISPLAY=':0'
export HOME='/home/mprythero'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LANGUAGE='en_US'
export LOGNAME='root'
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
export MAIL='/var/mail/root'
export NLSPATH='/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat'
export OLDPWD='/opt/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.3.0'
export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
export PWD='/home/mprythero/axis2-1.7.4/bin'
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export SUDO_COMMAND='/home/mprythero/Downloads/SoapUI-x64-5.3.0.sh'
export SUDO_GID='1000'
export SUDO_UID='1000'
export SUDO_USER='mprythero'
export TAR_OPTIONS='--no-same-owner'
export TERM='xterm-256color'
export USER='root'
export USERNAME='root'
export XAUTHORITY='/home/mprythero/.Xauthority'
export XFILESEARCHPATH='/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt'
./wsdl2java.sh: 23: ./wsdl2java.sh: =/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: not found
```

But, following the advice of another post, I have gone into my wsdl2java.sh file and edited it to include the following:

```
$JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export $JAVA_HOME
PATH=PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

At the moment, SOAPUI is pointing the Axis to: /home/myusername/axis2-1.7.4 (which is correct).

So what might I be doing wrong?

PS, before I forgot, when I echo $JAVA_HOME it does return back the correct location: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Thanks again! Matt

Comment: Change this `PATH=PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` to `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Please you have a syntax error in the lines you added:

This: `PATH=PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`, should be `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`.